# Is there a power of 3 and power of 7 that are equal?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been trying to find a set of values $(a,b)\in\mathbb Z^+$ which satisfy the following relationship:

$3^a = 7^b$

I haven not been able to find a value that can satisfy this and I also can't find a way disprove it.

Is there a theorem that I am missing?

Comment: They are distinct prime numbers, so this can never happen unless $a=b=0$.

Comment: **Hint** $\,3\nmid 7^b\,$ since $\!\bmod 3\!:\ 7^b\equiv 1^b\equiv 1\,$ (in case you don't yet know FTA or equivalents). You can also instead use the Binomial Theorem $\,(1+2\cdot 3)^b = 1 + 3(\cdots)\,$ if you don't know modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theorem you are missing is the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) which states that every integer factors uniquely as a product of prime integers.

Comment: @Sphero There are no pairs except for $(0,0)$, because otherwise $3^a$ and $7^b$ are both prime factorizations of numbers, and they are necessarily different.

Answer (score 1):

For fun:

Assume there are $m,n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, s.t.

$3^n=7^m.$

Euclid's lemma:

If a prime $p$ divides $ab$,  $a,b$, integers,

then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

$3|3^n$, and $3^n=7^m$, implies $3|7^m.$

But $3$ does not divide $7.$

A contradiction.

Can you show that

$3\not | 7^m$  repeatedly using Euclid's lemma ?

Answer (score -3):

You can prove that differently as well.

Since $a,b$ are integers, $\frac{a}{b}$ is rational by definition.

But:

$$3^a=7^b \to a\log 3 = b\log 7 \to \frac{a}{b} = \frac{\log7}{\log3}$$ Which is an irrational number. Hence, there are not integers $a,b$ such that: $3^a=7^b$

Comment: Why downvoted? Is it a wrong proof? Please specify downvoter!

Comment: The reason that this is downvoted is that it is circular.  How do you prove that $\log 7 / \log 3$ is irrational?  The standard proof depends on knowing that $3^a = 7^b$ has no non-zero solutions, so the only way to avoid circularity is for you to establish irrationality **without** appealing to this fact.

Comment: Thanks @ErickWong for the clarification.

Comment: So, I am keeping this answer to avoid such ways.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Some people dislike the (relatively minor) impact of the downvotes on their reputation score, but I agree that is useful to keep this answer here (in some form) as an example of a "wrong" answer that has educational value in the comments.